# iOS Login with Twitter

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter

I am developing an iOS 7 application that allows users to connect to their Twitter accounts. Should I follow the same process as creating a Facebook application and register it ? Is there any SDK that allows to authenticate via Twitter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the Twitter account defined by the user in iOS Settings, or register your own Twitter application on https://apps.twitter.com/.

You can use the third-party library [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) in both cases.